# How can I solve warning when I install chocolatey?

Tags: chocolatey

When I install chocolatey, I get error like this :

[image]

```
...

WARNING: It's very likely you will need to close and reopen your shell
  before you can use choco.
...

WARNING: You can safely ignore errors related to missing log files when
  upgrading from a version of Chocolatey less than 0.9.9.
  'Batch file could not be found' is also safe to ignore.
  'The system cannot find the file specified' - also safe.
WARNING: Not setting tab completion: Profile file does not exist at
'C:\Users\Chelsea
\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1'.

...
```

How can I solve the error?

Comment: Adding the error text as text (if possible) would be helpful to have in addition to the image

Comment: @dsstorefile Yes. I mean warning

Comment: @bertieb I update my question

Comment: You have three warnings, only one, is important.  So which warning are you worried about.  Have you closed and reopened your PowerShell prompt?

Answer (score 9):

Here's the solution for the tab completion warning:

1. Open a PowerShell session and run: `notepad $profile` This opens the profile file in Notepad.
2. Copy and paste the following code into Notepad and save the file:

```
# Chocolatey profile
$ChocolateyProfile = "$env:ChocolateyInstall\helpers\chocolateyProfile.psm1"
if (Test-Path($ChocolateyProfile)) {
  Import-Module "$ChocolateyProfile"
}
```

3. Restart PowerShell

Source: https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/troubleshooting#why-does-choco-tab-not-work-for-me

Comment: I think you mean `chocolateyProfile.ps1`

Comment: On what chocolatey version are you seeing `chocolateyProfile.ps1`? On 0.10.15 it’s `.psm1`.

Comment: Never mind. I wasn't familiar with PowerShell modules

Comment: After doing the above points (thanks!), I then got "execution of scripts is disabled on this system."

Fixed by following steps in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-says-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system:

`Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`

Answer (score 3):

Just ran into this warning myself. It occurs because there is not an existing PowerShell profile for your Windows user.

To create a profile, open a PowerShell session and enter:

```
if (!(Test-Path -Path $PROFILE)) {
  New-Item -ItemType File -Path $PROFILE -Force
}
```

I pulled the above code from [Microsoft's documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7#how-to-create-a-profile). The page covers a lot more about profiles if you are interested.